# SNI: Can I find out which hosts share the same IP?

Tags: ssl-certificate, host, sni

The setup is the following:

I know that a host uses SNI (e.g. universal.at on IP 91.236.122.125, the [test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=universal.at&s=91.236.122.125) says so). I know that I can find out **one** other host that is also hosted on the same IP address by finding the default certificate that is delivered by the IP address by

```
curl -v https://91.236.122.125
```

So I can see that www.lidl-reisen.de is also hosted on this IP address.
Are there further methods/tools to find out if there are even more hosts running on this IP address?

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "find all domains on an ip" gives these three options

- [Reverse IP Lookup 1](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/)
- [Reverse IP Lookup 2](http://viewdns.info/)
- [Reverse IP Lookup 3](http://viewdns.info/reverseip/)

However this isn't a foolproof system, reverse IP databases are incomplete. I don't think there's an authoritative way to work this out, other than looking at the web server configuration.

Comment: These tests say, that they find only 1 domain for 91.236.122.125.

Comment: I guess then the reverse IP databases aren't complete. Many of them say they're not complete.